# Executing Pentaho transformation(ktr) using node js with Pentaho CE

Tags: pentaho, transformation

I can able to successfully execute the .ktr files using browser and as well as using postman tool by using below url

http://localhost:8089/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=D:\Pentaho\ktr\MyJson_to_Database.ktr

But I want to automate the process and this ktr and it need to accept a json file as input(right now the json data is in side the ktr file itself). As I am using NodeJS to automate the ktr executing processing, I am trying to use wreck and post method to execute it(I am new to wreck), I am facing difficulties to identify the problem whether the error is due to wrek or kettle transformation itself

In the mean time I am trying to execute it without passing path as query string in url and instead I want to use it in body, I have searched google with no success so far.

EDIT 1
I am able to reach to the ktr file from NodeJS Microservice and now the challenge is to read the file path inside docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Could you work storing the json data in a file, and modifying/adding the transformation to read the file and pass the information in the file?

Comment: I am using docker and reading the ktr file from the container is again the big challenge, I am struggling to access the path of the file location inside a docker image

Comment: OK, after your edit of the question it seems more like a docker question, not a Pentaho question. So you need to easily share a file in your computer/server with your docker installation. There's a way to map a directory in your filesystem to a volume in your docker, so anything you put in that directory is accesible to docker. Google that, or ask the question in the docker forum if nobody here can answer that question, I haven't worked much in docker, so my answer would be the result of a google search the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response, If pentaho read the ktr file from filstream instead of physical path, I don;t need to store the ktr dynamically in a path , rather I will read the file stream and execute the ktr , Is there any way to execute file without passing file path? pass it in the body instead of query string?